# Unable to install firebase through npm

Tags: vue.js, npm

have been trying to install firebase through npm
using,

> Npm install --save firebase

then it return an error saying

> unexpected end of file while parsing input 3434DFDFSDFSGF.. and so on

and have tried diiferent solution on this platfoam such as

- Npm cache clean --force
- cache verify and so on...

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete node_modules folder, go to package.json file add `"firebase": "^7.7.0",` in dependencies. You can which ever version is required.
Then run command `npm install`.
If this doesn't work check node js version. Check if your node js version is supported or not by firebase version which is intalled.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this firebase-tools install problem with this command:
curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
This link is my reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools/v/9.23.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ellKF.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).